# MLR - Regression Benchmark Results - Visualisation

Tags: mlr

What are the options for visualising the results of a benchmark experiment of regression learners? For instance, `generateCalibrationData` doesn't accept a benchmark result object derived from a set of `regr.` learners. I would like something similar to the calibration plots available for classification.

In response to @LarsKotthoff's comment, I (the OP) have edited my original post to provide greater detail as to what functionality I am seeking.

Edit:

I'm looking for actual vs predicted calibration type plots such as simple scatterplots or something like the plots that exist under [Classifier Calibration](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/classifier_calibration/index.html). If I'm not mistaken, the following would make sense for regression problems (and seems to be what is done for Classifier Calibration):

- decide on a number of buckets to discretize the predictions on the x-axis, say 10 equal length bins (obviously you could continue with the `breaks` and `groups` interface to `generateCalibrationData` that currently exists)
- for each of those bins 10, calculate the mean "predicted" and plot (say via a dot) on the x-axis (possibly with some measure of variability) and join the dots across the 10 bins
- for each of those bins 10, calculate the mean "actual" and plot on the y-axis (possibly with some measure of variability) and join the dots
- provide some representation of volume in each bucket (as you've done for Classifier Calibration via "rag/rug" plots)

The basic premise behind my question is what kind of visualisation can be provided to help interpret an rsq, mae [etc](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/measures/index.html#regression) performance measure. There are many configurations of actual vs predicted that can lead to the same rsq, mae etc.

Once some plot exists, switching aggregation on/off would allow individual resampling results to be examined.

I would hope that the combination:

```
cal <- generateCalibrationData(bmr) 
plotCalibration(cal)
```

would be available for regression tasks, at present it doesn't seem to be (reproducible example below):

```
# Practice Data

library("mlr")
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing)
dim(BostonHousing)
head(BostonHousing)

# Define Nested Cross-Validation Strategy

cv.inner <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2)
cv.outer <- makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 6)

# Define Performance Measures

perf.measures <- list(rsq, mae)

# Create Task

bh.task <- makeRegrTask(id = "bh",
                        data = BostonHousing, 
                        target = "medv")

# Create Tuned KSVM Learner

ksvm <- makeLearner("regr.ksvm")

ksvm.ps <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("C", values = 2^(-2:2)),
                        makeDiscreteParam("sigma", values = 2^(-2:2)))

ksvm.ctrl <- makeTuneControlGrid()

ksvm.lrn = makeTuneWrapper(ksvm, 
                           resampling = cv.inner,
                           measures = perf.measures,
                           par.set = ksvm.ps, 
                           control = ksvm.ctrl, 
                           show.info = FALSE)

# Create Tuned Random Forest Learner

rf <- makeLearner("regr.randomForest",
                  fix.factors.prediction = TRUE)    

rf.ps <- makeParamSet(makeDiscreteParam("mtry", values = c(2, 3, 5)))

rf.ctrl <- makeTuneControlGrid()

rf.lrn = makeTuneWrapper(rf, 
                         resampling = cv.inner,
                         measures = perf.measures,
                         par.set = rf.ps, 
                         control = rf.ctrl, 
                         show.info = FALSE)

# Run Cross-Validation Experiments   

bh.lrns = list(ksvm.lrn, rf.lrn)        

bh.bmr <- benchmark(learners = bh.lrns, 
                    tasks = bh.task, 
                    resampling = cv.outer, 
                    measures = perf.measures, 
                    show.info = FALSE)

# Calibration Charts

bh.cal <- generateCalibrationData(bh.bmr)
plotCalibration(bh.cal)
```

which yields:

```
> bh.cal <- generateCalibrationData(bh.bmr)

Error in checkPrediction(x, task.type = "classif", predict.type = "prob") : 

  Prediction must be one of 'classif', but is: 'regr'

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)

attached base packages:

[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:

[1] mlbench_2.1-1     ROCR_1.0-7        gplots_3.0.1      mlr_2.9           
[5] stringi_1.1.1     ParamHelpers_1.10 ggplot2_2.1.0     BBmisc_1.10      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

 [1] digest_0.6.9        htmltools_0.3.5     R6_2.2.0            splines_3.2.3          
 [5] scales_0.4.0        assertthat_0.1      grid_3.2.3          stringr_1.0.0          
 [9] bitops_1.0-6        checkmate_1.8.2     gdata_2.17.0        survival_2.38-3        
[13] munsell_0.4.3       tibble_1.2          randomForest_4.6-12 httpuv_1.3.3           
[17] parallelMap_1.3     mime_0.5            DBI_0.5-1           labeling_0.3           
[21] chron_2.3-47        shiny_1.0.0         KernSmooth_2.23-15  plyr_1.8.4             
[25] data.table_1.9.6    magrittr_1.5        reshape2_1.4.1      kernlab_0.9-25         
[29] ggvis_0.4.3         caTools_1.17.1      gtable_0.2.0        colorspace_1.2-6       
[33] tools_3.2.3         parallel_3.2.3      dplyr_0.5.0         xtable_1.8-2           
[37] gtools_3.5.0        backports_1.0.4     Rcpp_0.12.4
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [learning curves](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/learning_curve/index.html)? The [benchmark experiments tutorial page](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/benchmark_experiments/index.html) also has lots of examples of visualizations.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff, I have tried to be more precise with my question, please see the edit to my original post.

Comment: `mlr` doesn't support this at the moment and we have no plans for adding it.

Comment: You could just take the predicted and actual values and plot those (and/or bin before plotting).